# A probability proposition that goes against the intuition

Tags: probability

What is the probability of guessing three exact numbers where the range for each of them 1 - 10^62?
A quick response would be 1/10^186

Now if there is a condition that three numbers (N1, N2, N3) should be such that N1 > N2 > N3, what is the probability of guessing three exact numbers?
Intuitively it feels that this would change the odds considerably, but please correct me, I understand that this condition affects the probability only by a factor of 6 because there are 6 permutations possible for N1, N2, & N3 (ignoring the equivalence relationships) and the solution space is just one of them.

so the probability is 6/10^186.

I teach a group of students basic probability. Is there a way to help them better visualize or understand this topic (if I am correct)?

Comment: Did you perhaps mean to write $\frac{1}{6} 10^{-186}$ right at the end?

Comment: well if I am aware that the correct exact numbers follow the condition that N1 > N2 > N3, then the probability of guessing is increased by a factor of 6. So it is 6/10^186

Comment: Five incompatible permutations and one compatible permutation means that (slightly less than) one-sixth of the orderings satisfy $n_1 > n_2 > n_3$.

Comment: Note that the answer of $10^{186}$ is only correct if you allow for all three numbers to be the same. Accordingly, you can not just divide by $6$ to get the answer, since if at least two of the numbers $N_1,N_2,N_3$ are the same, no permutation of these values will yield an outcome with strict inequalities.

Comment: This is a a tricky question. Let's consider the case that the numbers should be in the range 1, 2, 3. Obviously my guess for the first riddle would be the set {1, 2, 3} and I would be correct with probability one. Now in the second riddle if with equal probability I would guess one of the tuples (1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 2), (2, 1, 3), (2, 3, 1), (3, 1, 2), (3, 2, 1) then, as Erik says, my probability of being right becomes 1/6th of what it was before. But of course I am not crazy. Knowing that N1 > N2 > N3 I will not guess (1, 2, 3) for (N1, N2, N3) and I will guess (N3, N2, N1) so I'm back at prob 1

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: So when you say 'guessing' you have take into account that the 'guesser' knows something about that small numbers have bigger probability of being N3 and smaller of being N1 and that they try to reason with that in order to optimize their probability of succes... Unless you explicitly stipulate that the guessers don't try to optimize anything at all and guess according to some simpler model

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the best approach here is to look at it as a counting problem.

- First count the number of triples $(n_1, n_2, n_3)$ with $10^{62} \geq n_1 > n_2 > n_3 \geq 1$. Call this number $M$.
- If, from the perspective of the guesser, all $M$ triples are equally likely to be correct, then by guessing one of them the probability of guessing correctly is $1/M$ and we cannot do better.

The question is now: what is $M$?

The possibilities for the middle number $n_2$ range from $2$ to $10^{62} - 1$ and for each fixed $n_2$ there are $n_2 - 1$ possibilities for $n_3$ and $10^{62} - n_2$ possibilities for $n_1$. Thus we get the sum:

$$M = \sum_{n_2 = 2}^{10^{62} - 1} (n_2 - 1)(10^{62} - n_2)$$

Now how to simplify this? The summand is a quadratic polynomial, so a good starting point is to look up the standard formulas for sums of consecutive squares and sums of numbers in arithmetic progressions and then combine them in the appropriate way.

Comment: I am looking for an approximate. Would you not agree that it is 6/10^186?

Comment: Approximations are dangerous thing. As you write in the title of the post probability often goes against the intuition. To see if this approximation does or does not make sense the best is to compute the exact answer along the lines I sketched above  and see if the approximation is good or bad. Even better: to do the same comparison between approximation and exact answer for various versions of the problem where the number $10^{62}$ is replaced by small, intermediate and large numbers so that you get an idea if the approximation gets better or worse if this number grows.

Comment: These things are hard to predict because intuition can be deceiving. Also in probability theory there is a long tradition of only using approximations that get better and better as the numbers involved grow, so it makes sense to check if this one falls in that category